# SignatureDoesNotMatch AWS S3 Presigned url with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to reverse-proxy the requests from clients using a NodeJS script by generating pre-signed urls of the requested s3 objects as follows

for example, if a user opens the website as follows: build.localhost:8080, the build subdomain will be the folder, and the NodeJS proxy will load the index.html file inside the build folder.

Inside this build folder, I have uploaded all the build files generated by npm run build command, so that I can serve the static site with the NodeJS script.

Here's my code

```
const express = require('express');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'saml'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

function getPreSignedUrl(key){
    const myBucket = 'test-react-bucket-dev';
    const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5;
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
            Bucket: myBucket,
            Key: key,
            Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
        }, (err, url) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(url);
        });
    });
}

const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
    const hostname = req.hostname;
    const subdomain = hostname.split('.')[0];

    let key = subdomain + (req.path === '/' ? '/index.html' : req.path);

    try {
        const resolvesTo = await getPreSignedUrl(key);
        proxy.web(req, res, { target: resolvesTo, changeOrigin: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Error proxying the request");
    }
});

proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, res) => {
    const url = req.url;
    req.rawHeaders = []
    if (url === '/')
        proxyReq.path += 'index.html';

    console.log(req.rawHeaders)
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Reverse Proxy Running..${PORT}`));
```

and here's the error

```
<Error class="hidden">
<link type="text/css" id="dark-mode" rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
<style type="text/css" id="dark-mode-сustom-style"/>
<style type="text/css" id="dark-mode-theme-changer-style"/>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>ASIAR---REDACTED---EIYB</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>GET 1707814358 x-amz-security-token:FwoGZXIvYXdzEKf//////////wEaDDy3nYkyTaxu1hEt6iLnAcXSYnhu0Oq0K7AeEc/quuBjIyqMfZON6gbHFZ3/ZLi7yDwPtdlKsiacTDSKiav1XuQI1WP+aXePJ+RwgtJesC177Jmfg=/index.html /test-react-bucket-jk/build/index.html</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>mlC4fkhNSMavJk8R45i6T+QRBr8=</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>47 45 54 0a 0a 0a 31 37 30........</StringToSignBytes>
<RequestId>S3T66NPSHTKCDAQ7</RequestId>
<HostId>7EPjXVhzo2S3fBt7fNivJjlnpzcM7Ii9lbsQG4rXYDsoI25+vYvCMS6Cfy1uvVpkHRQVBsqZZI8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x-amz-security-token:FwoGZXIvYXdzEKf//////////wEaDDy3nYkyTaxu1hEt6iLnAcXSYnhu0Oq0K7AeEc/quuBjIyqMfZON6gbHFZ3/ZLi7yDwPtdlKsiacTDSKiav1XuQI1WP+aXePJ+RwgtJesC177Jmfg=/index.html
```

This is not what a security token should look like. Mind the extra `/index.html` at the end.

You code looks good, but `http-proxy` is appending the extra `/index.html` to the query string. Apparently it treats `target` as the base URL for the proxied requests, to which the path has to be appended.

Note that using pre-signed requests this way is a little bit unorthodox, albeit perfectly valid.

If your goal is to make a completely transparent proxy, it would probably be easier to use `s3.getObject` and pipe its results upstream.

If you it's OK for your clients to communicate with S3 directly, you can just return a 302 redirect to the presigned URL. This will save you some bandwidth and CPU on communicating with S3.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how I can remove the appended query string. My old code uses s3.getObject and it is slower, also my org does not allow me to set the bucket public, so I wanted to generate pre-signed urls and reverse proxy them back to the client.

Comment: setting proxyReq.path = resolvesTo fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: `s3.getObject` does just that under the hood: signs the request, sends it to S3 and waits for the response. As I said, this is a perfectly valid use case, especially if it does help with performance. You don't have to make the bucket public to use 302 redirects: the whole intent of presigned URLs is that they be given out to third parties, and be only good for a limited period of time.

Comment: yes, that's what I wanted, I was using s3.getObject, and the server used to wait for the response, which is pretty slow. And reverse proxying the pre-signed urls is way faster compared to my old code.